# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Server ALPNProcessors - WireMock

Tags: java, wiremock

I am trying to run unit tests (that use Wiremock) on my maven project and the following error is observed.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Server ALPNProcessors
```

I tried adding the `alpn-boot-8.1.12.v20180117.jar` to the `Xbootclasspath` as follows

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/alpn-boot-8.1.12.v20180117.jar
```

and have put it in the `jvm.config` file in the `.mvn` directory of my project and verified that it is being set by doing a `ps -ef | grep Xbootclasspath` but still I am getting the same error.

It is working on Windows machine with **Java 8 u191** and without adding any `Xbootclasspath` but not on Linux with **Java 8 u181**

I also tried adding the following dependency to my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-alpn-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.20.v20190813</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

but still did not work.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${real.base.dir}</workingDirectory>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <log4j.configurationFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/log4j.xml</log4j.configurationFile>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-jars</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/lib</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M3</maven.surefire.version>

        <javax.validation.version>2.0.1.Final</javax.validation.version>
        <syncope.version>2.1.5</syncope.version>
        <resteasy.client.version>4.4.2.Final</resteasy.client.version>
        <jax.rs.version>2.1.1</jax.rs.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit.jupiter.version>

        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <real.base.dir>${basedir}</real.base.dir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jax.rs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.syncope.identityconnectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Start Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End Test dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Could you share your pom.xml and command how you run tests.

Comment: You might have case sensitive issue with the path, it need to be exact in linux

Comment: @slesh `mvn clean test`

Comment: @user7294900 I did an `ll <file_path>` on the path and the path exists

Comment: if the path is `MyPath` and you enter `mypath` it won't work, because file/folder is case sensitive

Answer (score 35):

Just incase any M1 Mac users stumble onto this page like I did.

---

My Issue -

My spring boot project with wiremock tests, would run on my old intel mac but failed to run when I moved to my new M1 Mac.

_ _

I had 2 error messages

- java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Server ALPNProcessors!
- Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no conscrypt_openjdk_jni-osx-aarch_64

---

Fix -

I needed a property to test.application

> wiremock.server.httpsPort=-1

Comment: thanks, it saved me some hours!

Comment: Thanks! However this just moved me forward to a Luna JIT something compiler error...

Comment: M1 Pro here, confirmed this fixes it. Even though it says -1 is the default value...

Comment: The issue was solved for me with the latest Spring Cloud dependency `2021.0.2`.

Comment: thanks, worked. M1 Pro here with wiremock lib version 2.2.8.RELEASE

Comment: Experienced same issue. Tests ran well in my intel pc and got above errors when deploying in AWS. provided solution worked for me too

Answer (score 3):

Specifying the version for `wiremock-jre8-standalone` will do the trick. Issue was addressed in version 2.32.0 as specified in [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/1724):

```
# Gradle
testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8-standalone:2.32.0'

#Maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.32.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in combination with Mac M1 and/or spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner :-(

Answer (score 2):

To avoid `No Server ALPNProcessors` error with newer version of wiremock, like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
    <version>2.30.1</wiremock.version>
</dependency>
```

you can try below dependencies.

**For JDK 9 and later**

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-alpn-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-alpn-java-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

References: 
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1894
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#alpn-jdk9

**For JDK 8**

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-alpn-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

References: 
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1894 https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#alpn-openjdk8

Answer (score 0):

Change wiremock to an elder version solve this issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Needed for the SSLContextFactory$Client class -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.14.v20181114</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In short, the new version of jetty will make use of alpn module, while jdk8 do not have this module.
For detail, please refer to https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-alpn

Comment: Could you explain which technical change in `2.21.0 +`  versions of `wiremock-jre8` caused the issue?